# Custom command not echoing anything in the terminal

Tags: rust, terminal

The following code lets you define custom commands in the terminal. Each custom command has a `key` (which triggers the command), a `description`, and a `shell_command` (the actual command).

```
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use std::process::Command;
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;

struct CustomCommand {
    key: char,
    description: &'static str,
    shell_command: &'static str,
}

impl CustomCommand {
    fn execute_shell_command(&self) {
        let output = Command::new("sh")
            .arg("-c")
            .arg(self.shell_command)
            .output();

        match output {
            Ok(output) => {
                if output.status.success() {
                    println!("Command executed successfully\r\n");
                } else {
                    println!("Command execution failed\r\n");
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error executing command: {:?}\r\n", e);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Turn on raw mode for the terminal
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    // Define the available commands

    let commands = vec![CustomCommand {
        key: 'c',
        description: "This is a custom command",
        shell_command: "echo 'Custom command executed'",
    }];

    // Print the messages to the terminal
    write!(stdout, "Please select a command:\r\n").unwrap();

    // List the custom commands for the user
    for command in &commands {
        write!(stdout, "{}  {}\r\n", command.key, command.description).unwrap();
    }

    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    // Read input from stdin
    let input = stdin().keys();

    // Loop over each key that is pressed
    for key in input {
        // Match the key against the available commands
        match key.unwrap() {
            // If the key matches a command, execute it and break the loop
            Key::Char(k) if commands.iter().any(|c| c.key == k) => {
                let command = commands.iter().find(|c| c.key == k).unwrap();
                command.execute_shell_command();
                break;
            }
            // Output other characters
            Key::Char(c) => {
                write!(stdout, "You pressed: {}\r\n", c).unwrap();
                stdout.flush().unwrap();
            }
            // If the key is anything else, ignore it
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

The command is being executed successfully, but is not echoing anything in the terminal:

```
Please select a command:
c  This is a custom command
Command executed successfully
alex@alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD:~/rust/cc$
```

Why is this, and how to fix it?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8ac4195c43ba6dde886e3c4ec15be63)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On success, `output` contains a `Vec<u8>` in its `stdout` member.
You can eventually convert it to a string and display it as some text.

```rust
if output.status.success() {
    println!("Command executed successfully\r\n");
    println!("bytes: {:?}", output.stdout);
    let text = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
    println!("text: {:?}", text);
}
```

If you are not interested in capturing the outputs of the command, you can simply use [`spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn); then the outputs of the command will naturally appear in the terminal.

Thanks to @JonasFassbender remark, [`.status()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) is even easier (it waits for the process to terminate, we don't have to).
Here is your code slightly modified.

```rust
    fn execute_shell_command(&self) {
        let status = Command::new("sh")
            .arg("-c")
            .arg(self.shell_command)
            .status();
        match status {
            Ok(status) => {
                if status.success() {
                    println!("Command executed successfully\r\n");
                } else {
                    println!("Command execution failed\r\n");
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error executing command: {:?}\r\n", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, could you show me an example of using `spawn();`?

Comment: Just replacing your `output()` call with [`status()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) should be enough. Like `spawn`, it does not capture the `stdout` of your child process. Unlike `spawn` it waits for your child process to finish, returning the `ExitStatus`.

Comment: @JonasFassbender It worked, thanks. I guess using `status()` is the same as doing `spawn()`, then `child.wait()`.

Comment: @alexchenco I looked at the implementation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/process.rs.html#936-941) and you are right, that is exactly what is happening